# TypeError: index '_id' cannot be applied to Cursor instances

Tags: python, mongodb

I need some help trying to join 2 collections. One is website visitor profiles and another of a visit on the website. I want to add every visit to the corresponding profile in an array of objects. Every visit object has a field 'v' with the object ID of the visitor it belongs to. find_one() works perfectly but find() results in  TypeError: index '_id' cannot be applied to Cursor instances.

[image: visit] [image: visitor]

Code:

```
Visitorvisits = []
visitors = []

visitors.append(visitors_collection.find())

for v in visitors:
    Visitorvisits.append(visits_collection.find({"v": v['_id']}))  #find_one()
    v['visits'] = Visitorvisits
    jointable.insert_one(v)
```

[image]

Here we see the result of find_one(), it added an array with 1 object inside but I need all objects not 1.

Comment: To get related data from another collection, use `$lookup` aggregation stage.